# "Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'

Tags: c++, constructor

I recently started learning C++ and I'm having trouble with my constructor. Simple example of my class file

```
class Test {

private:

    char *type;

public:

    Test(const char *type); //this is my constructor

};
```

Now I have a problem when I'm trying to implement the constructor.

```
Test::Test(const char *type){

this-> type = *type;

}
```

I get the error: "Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'. Now I searched this site and the web for solutions. But didn't find anything for my specific problem. I can imagine that the solution is quite simple, but for the love of me, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Omit the dereference operator (`*`) and resolve `const`-ness, perhaps do a copy of the buffer...

Comment: Go back to whatever book you're having, and read again about the *dereference operator* `*`, and what it does.

Comment: Given the definition `char *type`, a statement with `*type` is a `char` - the `*` dereferences the  pointer.

Comment: If I've said it once, I've said it a thousand times. Just use a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Test::Test(const char *type){

this-> type = type;

}
```

and also as erip said try using `std::string`. Try using STL as much as possible.

Comment: I tried that already. Gives me the error "Invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'.

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem(s):**

```
char *type;
```

This declares `type` as a *pointer to `char`*. It *points* to some memory, where (hopefully) there is an array of characters, ending with a null byte.

```
Test(const char *type);
```

This means your class has a constructor that *receives* a *pointer to `const char`*.

```
this->type = ...
```

This *assigns* to your member `type`, i.e. the *pointer* `type` is made to *point* at a *different* memory location.

```
... = *type;
```

Unfortunately, using the operator `*` on the argument `type` means that you are not assigning a pointer, but **the value of the first character `type` points to**, which is -- of course -- not a valid memory addess.

Even if you omit the `*` operator, you still have a problem:

- *member* `type` is a pointer to `char`.
- *argument* `type` is a pointer to `const char`.

You cannot assign something `const` to something non-`const`, at least not without a cast, and you *should* not do that, either.

It is also an example of a "shallow copy", i.e. your class will not have its own *copy* of the string it was constructed with, but only a pointer to some memory it has no control over. That's not a good design.

---

---

All in all, **the "solution"** here is:

**When programming in C++, do as C++ does.**

```
// Use std::string.
#include <string>

class Test {
    public:
        Test( const std::string & type ) : _type( type ) {}

    private:
        std::string _type;
};
```

If you **insist** on using C strings, that would look somewhat like this:

```
#include <cstring>

class Test {
    public:
        Test( const char * type )
        {
            // Assign memory and *copy* the string
            _type = new char[ std::strlen( type ) + 1 ];
            std::strcpy( _type, type );
        }

        ~Test()
        {
            // Remember to *release* the memory when you are done
            delete [] _type;
        }

    private:
        char * _type;
};
```

Comment: Good answer and nice explanation why other, "easier" solutions are bad. +1

Comment: The example using c-cstrings is calling strlen twice, unnecessarily. The preferable solution would be to use `memcpy`, correct? 

`size_t len = std::strlen(type) + 1;
_type = new char[len];
std::memcpy(_type, type, len);`

Added benefit: it will be slightly faster since `memcpy` does not check for 0 at each char.

Comment: @MaxNoe: There is only one `strlen()` there. Whether you check the byte counter for zero or the copied byte for zero should not make much of a difference. And for example purposes I prefer not to worry too much about microoptimization, and prefer expressive code, i.e. `strcpy()` over `memcpy()` because I am copying a string here, not generic memory.